# What kind of Lat-Lon representation is this?

Tags: gps

I have a set of latitude and longitude co-ordinates which looks like,

- Lat=9339452, Lon=4294611105
- Lat=9386855, Lon=4294690789
- Lat=9388898, Lon=4294697554
- Lat=9389437, Lon=4294725570

I need a formula to convert the above given GPS co-ordinates to radians or degrees. Please let me know if you are aware of such GPS representation.

Comment: Do you know what location these coordinates are meant to refer to?

Comment: Yes. They refer regions around York and Leeds in the United Kingdom. But I do not know the exact location.

Comment: Maybe you will have more luck [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It is garbage, wrongly imported. (signed vs unsigned int, see answer of Mirar) but it remains garbage. Try to fix that if it is your bug, or demand a fix from the data provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second number (4294...) is a negative signed number (INT32) read as UINT32.

This would give

```
Lat=9339452, Lon=-356191
Lat=9386855, Lon=-276507
Lat=9388898, Lon=-269742
Lat=9389437, Lon=-241726
```

which would match the lat/lon coordinates better (lon=53ish, lat=-1.5ish).

Convert these numbers from radians to degrees and divide by 1e7:

```
Lat=53.51111825650155, Lon=-2.04082410005443,
Lat=53.78271744012741, Lon=-1.58426841058238,
Lat=53.79442296788193, Lon=-1.54550781574178,
Lat=53.79751121039769, Lon=-1.38498795985793,
```

ie, f(x) = x * 180/pi * 1e-7

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It helps!